# If an app uses normal-priority GCM messages will it always have access to the network?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Sometimes when I receive a normal-priority GCM message in my Android app the network doesn't seem to be available. Do normal-priority GCM messages automatically grant an app temporary exemptions to Android M's new [Doze and App Standby](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) sleep conditions (namely restricting network access)?

Full Context:
I've implemented an App prior to Android-M's release that uses a GCM messaging to tickle installed app instances to download updates on-demand. This is a [best practice](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html) over polling for updates.

Android-M introduces Doze and AppStandby which seem able to restrict network access when apps aren't using the the [new high-priority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) message type.

Should I switch these tickle messages to high-priority or will I have network access when I receive normal-priority messages? My testing with Android M Previews seems to indicate the network sometimes isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

Network access MIGHT be available and you should not switch your message type to high-priority just to ensure network access is available. You should only switch your message type if the GCM Message is of urgent need to a user on that device. A general rule would be that the notification would fall under the HIGH category when considering the guidance around [creating notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html). If you currently use the same GCM messages for periodic sync requests as well as urgent messages you should separate them.

A little more detail on the "Network access MIGHT be available":

As of [October 1st](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-google-cloud-messaging-handles-doze.html) up-to-date versions of Google Play services correlate the delivery of GCM normal-priority messages with Doze's maintenance mode, so the network typically won't be restricted. A developer asking this question should consider that a robust app will typically deal with Doze and real-world network connectivity problems at the same time. The app would typically:

- Not execute network work in the callbacks invoked when receiving GCM messages.
- When a GCM message callback is received by the app the app would schedule work using GCMNetworkManager, JobScheduler, or at the very least SyncAdapter.

The network scheduling routines:

- Correlate work execution within Doze maintenance windows.
- Allow additional granular scheduling parameters that allow for better user experiences, particular with regard to battery life (Wifi vs Cellular, Charging, etc).
- Acquire wakelocks to try to prevent the device from going asleep halfway through performing work. Doze will sometimes ignore wakelocks, such as at the end of the maintenance window.
- Have built-in ways of indicating work is complete and rescheduling when appropriate.
- Reschedule work using exponential back-off potentially providing a developer's server relief during outages as well as providing users with better battery life under network connectivity issues.

Note: When testing with a device, including one with Android M Preview, make sure Google Play services is fully up-to-date before testing (v8.1+). This typically requires opening the Google Play store app and accepting the Terms of Service.